# How to get JSX tag attributes in functional react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to understand how to access custom attributes to component tags in react.
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything searching the internet because I couldn't find out what to search for so that I don't get only tons of sites that explain how to pass props to components.

I am using react-color and it sends me an object in "e" to handleChange function when something changes in the color picker.

```
const colorPicker = () => {
    return(
        <SketchPicker name="fill" onChange={handleChange} />
    );
}
```

With e.hex I can access the color in hex but how can I access the attribute "name"?

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("handleChange", e);
    context.object().set({fill: e.hex}); //<- works
    //context.object().set({e.name: e.hex}); doesn't work <- e.name is undefined
}
```

Comment: try `e.target.name`

Comment: e.target is undefined

Comment: it looks like this [onChange](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#api-onChange) takes in 2 arguments, so the signature should be: `handleChange = (color, event) => {}`, you can log the object reference with `console.log(event.target)`, but it doesn't look like `SketchPicker` is setting the html attribute

Comment: In the returned object there is a div but e.target.name doesn't exist. There is an id but that's always "" (empty string) even when I set <SketchPicker id="fill" ...

Comment: I thought react would bring a default functionality to access JSX attributes

Comment: e.target.name doesnt exist because the div I get in e is the div of the color picker and not of the react component.

Comment: react does support [html attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html), but it seems like react-color is not setting it on the proper div. then when you log the object, you don't see it. depending on where you click in the color picker, you will get a different div element too.

Comment: Yes exactly, it's always the specific div where I clicked (where I changed something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [onChange](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#api-onChange) method can receive two arguments, the color (in your example, that is **e**) and and event argument. Try accessing the second and see if the property is available in it. If it is, you're good to go, if it isn't:

Since react-color is a component you did not create from scratch, the only way to know how its props are handled is by checking its internal code and modify it if necessary. You will very likely not need/want to do that.

If the **name** property is very likely to be dynamic, pass it down to **colorPicker** and access it though props.name:

```
<SomeComponent>
  <ColorPicker name={'fill'}/>
</SomeComponent>
```

Then from within the ColorPicker component:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  context.object().set({[props.name]: e.hex}); 
}
```

By the way, if you are computing property names, you should use square brackets **[]** such as in the example above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to clarify, you say I should create an own ColorPicker component and access the attribute there through normal props?

Comment: The colorPicker function you provided in your post is already a functional component which returns the SketchPicker,  so you just need to use it as such.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const handleChange = (e, target) => {
    console.log("handleChange", e);
    context.object().set({fill: e.hex}); //<- works
    context.object().set({target.name: e.hex});
}
```

It seems that react-color sends a second parameter into the handleChange function

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work. target.name is undefined.

Comment: this doesn't work, `target.name` is still undefined. also, not that the names matter _that_ much, but the parameters should be `const handleChange = (color, event) => {}` from the [docs](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#api-onChange)

Comment: Yeah and in event or e is just the div of the color picker and not the object of the react component that's accessed by <SketchPicker />